# saving multiple records in bookshelf.js

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

How do i save multiple records  in bookshelf.js.

How do we save the following data without looping and inserting

```
[
  {name: 'Person1'},
  {name: 'Person2'}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var Accounts = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: Account
});

var accounts = Accounts.forge([
  {name: 'Person1'},
  {name: 'Person2'}
])

Promise.all(accounts.invoke('save')).then(function() {
  // collection models should now be saved...
});
```

Plz see comment: Invoke has now been replaced by invokeThen

```
accounts.invokeThen('save').then(function() {
  // ... all models in the collection have been saved
});
```

Comment: Think invoke has been replace by invokeThen.

Comment: This doesn't really save them all at once. It will run a separate database query for each save.

Comment: @Asher : How do you save all the records in one query ?

Comment: To save multiple records in one query, you should use bookshelf's instance of knex and call `.insert([<items>])`

Answer (score 6):

I think Bookshelf has been updated, replacing 'invoke' with 'invokeThen'.

```js
var Accounts = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
  model: Account
});
    
var accounts = Accounts.forge([
  {name: 'Person1'},
  {name: 'Person2'}
]) 

accounts.invokeThen('save').then(function() {
  // ... all models in the collection have been saved
});
```

Comment: how can i update multiples rows in Bookshelf with using where clause

Comment: Does it save all of them at once or one by one?

Answer (score 2):

I tried using forge following up with invokeThen but it failed in my case. It seems we can use the model itself without having to create a separate collection instance.Here, Employee is a Model and not a separate collection object.

```
Employee.collection()
  .add(employees)
  .invokeThen('save');
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the third argument in the invokeThen method as given below to execute the insert method.

```
const payload = [{name: 'Person1'},
      {name: 'Person2'}]

Users.collection(payload).invokeThen("save", null, { method: "insert" }).then(result => {
// further logics
})
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks